# Running tests on the output of Jupyter Notebook cells

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am using Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab for teaching the basics of Python.

Is it possible to run tests on previous cell's standard output without suppressing the output of a cell?

Magics `%%capture` with standard config redirects stdout. I'd like to be able to still see the output of the cell before running the tests.

e.g.

```
[cell 1] >> print('Hello, world!')
Hello, world!
```

Testing cell:

```
[cell 2] >>  if (cell1.stdout == 'Hello, world!'):
         ...    print('Success!')
         ... else:
         ...    print('Tests failed')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is pretty simple, just wrap the `%%capture` magic with a custom function showing the captured output:

```
from IPython.core import magic

@magic.register_cell_magic
def non_suppressing_capture(variable, cell):
    get_ipython().magics_manager.magics['cell']['capture'](variable, cell)
    globals()[variable].show()
```

and (after execution of the above code) use it like this:

```
%%non_suppressing_capture cell1
print('Hello, world!')
```

Actually, your test will fail unless you add a new line character of the test string:

```
if cell1.stdout == 'Hello, world!\n':
    print('Success!')
else:
    print('Tests failed')
```

IPython magic is a powerful tool. You can find more advanced examples in documentation, see: [defining custom magics](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html) chapter and API docs: [core.magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magic.html), [core.magic_arguments](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magic_arguments.html).